# Retrofit parsing issue with GSON

Tags: android, json, web-services, retrofit2

I know this question has been asked many time.But I am not able to understand the soultion.

I am getting below error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Below is my code.

```
  PriceInterface priceInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(PriceInterface.class);

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("date", "today");
    params.put("circle", "Chandigarh");

    Call<PriceListBean> call = priceInterface.getMyThing(params);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<PriceListBean>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PriceListBean> call, Response<PriceListBean> response) {
            Log.e("response is","++++"+response.body().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PriceListBean> call, Throwable t) {

            Log.e("failure message is",""+t.getLocalizedMessage());
           // t.getLocalizedMessage();

        }
    });
```

Below is my json which I am getting from server.

```
 {
    "price": [{
        "id": 678,
        "date_time": "2017-07-25",
        "type": "Diesel",
        "place": "Chandigarh",
        "price": "55.75"
    }, {
        "id": 639,
        "date_time": "2017-07-25",
        "type": "Petrol",
        "place": "Chandigarh",
        "price": "64.74"
    }],
    "errorCode": 0,
    "errorDesc": "Success"
}
```

I have created Pojo for this.

```
public class PriceListBean {

@SerializedName("price")
@Expose
private List<Price> price = null;
@SerializedName("errorCode")
@Expose
private Integer errorCode;
@SerializedName("errorDesc")
@Expose
private String errorDesc;

public List<Price> getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(List<Price> price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public Integer getErrorCode() {
    return errorCode;
}

public void setErrorCode(Integer errorCode) {
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
}

public String getErrorDesc() {
    return errorDesc;
}

public void setErrorDesc(String errorDesc) {
    this.errorDesc = errorDesc;
}
```

}

This can be easily done with Volley or Gson But as I am trying to user Retrofit so I am stuck in this. I am not sure If I am getting right format json or not

Comment: You might be getting a wrong json data. The converter is expecting a JsonObject but its getting String instead. Do check your api in a rest client and kindly post the response here.

Comment: @SureshKumar I have checked the data on browser. and Also on POSTMAN. They both are showing correct format. Not sure how I can see the response in my code.

Comment: Could it be because of the "price" key which appears both at 1st and 2nd level of json?

Comment: This code works fine when making all the fields of the Price class Strings. So the problem is in your Price class I think, can you add the source of that class?

Comment: you can do one thing to check whether you are getting a correct resopnse or not add a response interceptor and check your rawResponse. if you don't know that i can add the code as an answer, i am not doing it caus its not a part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide us with your Price object 
off the top of my head your Price class should look something like this

```
public class Price {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private long id;
    @SerializedName("date_time")
    @Expose
    private String date_time;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("place")
    @Expose
    private String place;
    @SerializedName("price")
    @Expose
    private String price;

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setDate_time(String date_time) {
        this.date_time = date_time;
    }

    public String getDate_time() {
        return this.date_time;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    public void setPlace(String place) {
        this.place = place;
    }

    public String getPlace() {
        return this.place;
    }

    public void setPrice(String place) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }
}
```

Try this in place of your current Price object and lets know if the error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

your response getting list of data and then change this code..

```
 Log.e("response is","++++"+response.body().toString());
```

and used below code..

```
  @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<PriceListBean> call, Response<PriceListBean> response) {
        List<PriceListBean> data=response.body();
       // Log.e("response is","++++"+response.body().toString());
    }
```

and i hope you add below dependency into app level gradle file..

```
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```